# What am I doing wrong when combining objects with the module pattern

Tags: javascript, function, object, iife

This [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683125/combining-inheritance-with-the-module-pattern) did not help me, I failed on an interview because of a similar question.

The idea is to create a person `Object` that is a father of teacher and grandfather of Manager using `module pattern` and `inheritance`.
Something like that Manager->Teacher->Person

My code looks like that([My Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/E1CqQ1AeDxbKfFYepRSW)):

```
(function(undef)
{
    /**Waiting till document is ready before applying next functions*/
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var person = new APP.Person('Aria Stark','223232');
        document.write(person.getDetails());
    })();

     var APP = {};

     APP.Person =(function() {

        function Person(name, ID) {
            this.name = name;
            this.ID = ID;
        }

        Person.prototype.getDetails = function() {
            return " name: " + this.name + " ID: " + this.ID;
        };

        return Person;
    });

    APP.Teacher =(function () {

        function Teacher(name, ID, salary, hatColor) {
            APP.Person.call(this, name, ID);
            this.salary = salary;
            this.hatColor = hatColor;
        }

        Teacher.prototype = new APP.Person();

        Teacher.prototype.getDetails = function() {
            return APP.Person.call(this) + " Salary: " + this.salary + " Hat: " + this.hatColor;
        };

        return Teacher;
    });


    APP.Manager =(function () {

        function Manager(name, ID, salary, hatColor, car) {
            APP.Teacher.call(this, name, ID, salary, hatColor);
            this.car = car;
        }

        Manager.prototype = new APP.Teacher();

        Manager.prototype.getDetails = function() {
            return APP.Teacher.call(this) + " Car: " + this.car;
        };

        return Manager;
    });


})();
```

I get an error on the first line:

```
var person = new APP.Person('Aria Stark','22323');
```

The error is: `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

Can someone help me with with that? I'm also open to hear other improvements to this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you create (and call) a [self-executing function or IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
(function () {})();
```

Simply writing `(function () {})` does not call the function, it actually has no real effect in this case. With your way `APP.Person` will be a function, that returns another function (the constructor for `Person`) **when called** - it will not operate well with `new`.

Also, for the documentready, you don't want to execute the result of the `.ready` call, just pass the `function` as a parameter, it will be called when the event triggers:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
}); //removed () from here
```

[Plunk with these changes](http://plnkr.co/edit/jsG811KgPDpmHMLH43Z1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this answer leads to a new problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/fyg4JDBQp9DSzvI6pvOx?p=preview, when I try to create teacher object

Comment: @Canttouchit I will take a look. Meanwhile, please forget `document.write`, there is `console.log`, it is very useful.

Comment: Yeah forgot :  `return APP.Person.prototype.getDetails.call(this)`

Comment: @Canttouchit Yes, there was another issue. This is how you call the `getDetails` on `APP.Person`: `APP.Person.prototype.getDetails.call(this)`. Remember, `APP.Person` is a function, that has a `prototype` property, and you put `getDetails` on that one. [Working Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/2GhGvHXoHfVMUlVorUXS?p=info)

Answer (score 1):

All your objects are declared like this:

```
APP.X=(function() {
    function Y() {}
    Y.prototype.method= function() {};
    return Y;
});
```

That is not wrong in itself, though it is a bit odd. What you want to have is this:

```
APP.X=(function() {
    function X() {}
    X.prototype.method= function() {};
    return X;
})(); // actually call the anonymous function you used to encapsulate variables
```

Then again, why do you bother with an IIFE? You might just as well do this:

```
APP.X = function () {}
X.prototype.method= function() {};
```

Encapsulating them brings absolutely nothing, there is nothing private you are hiding from the outer scope.

---

Also, my post might be better suited for CodeReview than StackOverflow, but your inheritance model has significant issues. Your Teacher.prototype is an instance of Person created with no parameters. Only under highly restrictive circumstances will that be safe.

A better model would be this one:

```
Teacher = function(){
    Person.call(this /*, person parameters*/);
}
Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

There are many good answers on SO dealing with this specific issue, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005474/javascript-inheritance-with-unexpected-behaviour/20005732#20005732) is one from me.

Comment: The only thing he gains by the IIFE is better readability - stuff belonging together (the constructor and the methods for the prototype) is grouped, it becomes visually more comprehensible. But +1 of course.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of jQuery to create these things. Well, I have not very good exposer on this, but I tried to show the things you want to know:

```
// Creating Person Class
var Person = function(name, id){
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
};

Person.prototype.getInfo = function(){
    return "name: " + this.name + ",  id: " + this.id;
};

// Instance of Person
var x = new Person("Ashish", 1);
x.getInfo();

// Creating Teacher Class
var Teacher = function(name, id, salary, hatColor){
    Person.call(this, name, id);
    this.salary = salary;
    this.hatColor = hatColor;
};

// Inheriting Persons methods
Teacher.prototype = new Person();

// Adding new method to it
Teacher.prototype.getFullDetails = function(){
    return this.getInfo() + ", salary: " + this.salary + ", Hatcolor: " + this.hatColor;
}

// Instance of Teacher Class
var teacher = new Teacher("John", 2, 15000, "red");
teacher.getInfo(); //output: "name: John,  id: 2"
teacher.getFullDetails(); // output : "name: John,  id: 2, salary: 15000, Hatcolor: red"
console.log(teacher.salary); // output : 15000
```

So, above you can see:
- A `Person` class is created with 2 properties and one method.
- and then we created a `Teacher` class and inherited the method from `Person` class in it.
- and then added another method called `getFullDetails()` in it which accesses the method coming from `Person` class.

**And this is what you are doing in the DOM.ready:**

```
alert(x.getInfo()); // in my example:
```

In your example:

```
var APP = {};
APP.Person = function Person(name, ID) {
    this.name = name;
    this.ID = ID;
}

APP.Person.prototype.getDetails = function () {
    return " name: " + this.name + " ID: " + this.ID;
};

var person = new APP.Person('Aria Stark', '223232');
alert(person.getDetails());
```